# Timer methods not called

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have setup a timer:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer (1000);
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            ui.CldOnPhoneNumberSent(); // <- this method is not fired
        };
```

the second method is not called.
if i switch the methods as in:

```
timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
    ui.CldOnPhoneNumberSent(); 
    timer.Enabled = false; // <- this method is not called and the timer repeats
}
```

what's wrong?

**Edit:**
When the method is called from a timer, it's not called completely!:

```
timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
                ((Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
                ui.method1();
};

void method1()
{
   do something; //<-- called
   do Something; //<-- not called 
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger, set breakpoints and step through your code.

Comment: Could `CldOnPhoneNumberSent` be throwing an exception?  Have you run it in the debugger?

Comment: More specifically, the identifier `ui` suggests you're interacting with the UI in some way, presumably in a Winforms/WPF application? In that case, it's invariably going to fail, as you can't access those objects from threads other than the one they were created on. Are you sure you don't actually want to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead?

Comment: Never write a Timer.Elapsed event handler without using try/catch, it swallows exceptions without a diagnostic.  Favor System.Threading.Timer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with variable closure in the anonymous method - try using the `sender` value instead of referencing `timer`:

```
timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
        ((Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
        ui.CldOnPhoneNumberSent(); // <- this method is not fired
    };
```

Comment: Even if when the second method is called (after some configuration), the inner methods are not called competely! I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

As was said in comments, the most likely reason is that your `CldOnPhoneNumberSent()` throws some exception preventing further execution.

You should rewrite as follow:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer (1000);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
    ((Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        ui.CldOnPhoneNumberSent();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log exception
        // do something with it, eventually rethrow it
    }
};
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Note that is you are inside a WPF application and want to access object created in the UI thread, you may need to dispatch the call:

```
Action callback = ui.CldOnPhoneNumberSent;
var app = Application.Current;
if (app == null)
{
    // This prevents unexpected exceptions being thrown during shutdown (or domain unloading).
    return;
}
if (app.CheckAccess())
{
    // Already on the correct thread, just execute the action
    callback();
}
else
{
    // Invoke through the dispatcher
    app.Dispatcher.Invoke(callback);
}
```

As a final note, if you are using .Net 4.5 (with C# 5) you might consider using the [async/await pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) instead of System.Timers.Timer, which is easier to use and more readable:

```
private async Task YourMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000)
        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: true); // this makes sure continuation is on the same thread (in your case it should be the UI thread)
    try
    {
        ui.CldOnPhoneNumberSent();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log exception
        // do something with it, eventually rethrow it
    }
}
```